# Creating SVG path starting at point zero

Tags: svg, path, inkscape

I'm looking for a way to create a svg path starting in point zero M 0,0 ... ... .

In Inkscape the paths don't starting in point zero. There is another coordinate system internally. If I create a path in Inkscape starting in (0,0) and I use the path in other applications like websites, the image is not starting in (0,0).

Does anybody know a way to solve this problem?

Tanks for helping me.

BR
CPA

Comment: Can you show us a sample SVG demonstrating your problem?

Comment: Hi, I already found a solution. I had to create the shape or path in the upper left corner in Inkscape instead of the lower left corner where Inkscape has the coordinate origin.